# Error when trying to install cartopy python Anaconda

Tags: python, cartopy, geos

I am trying to install cartopy in my Anaconda installation, but it won't work.  Here are the error messages.  How do I get this package to install?  I tried installing using

```
pip install cartopy
```

and

```
conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```

Both give these errors:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: cartopy
  Building wheel for cartopy (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for cartopy (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build cartopy

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  command: 'C:\Users\ruben\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\ruben\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C

<string>:117: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.7.2 or 
later installed, or installation may fail.

Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\lib/cartopy/trace.obj
 trace.cpp
lib/cartopy/trace.cpp(719): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'geos_c.h': No 
such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed 
with exit code 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cartopy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cartopy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed 
directly
```

Anaconda gives me these errors:

```
conda install cartopy

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
```

Now it just sits there are spins.

I have the geos package installed.  I don't knw why it can't find the installation.

Comment: Can you show the command you ran? Which channels did you use?

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me in a Linux Mint system. I can see that OP's system is Windows, so not sure if it'll work for them also. But for folks on ubuntu/linux landing here,

We need to have libgeos-dev installed first:

```
sudo apt install libgeos-dev
```

got this from https://techoverflow.net/2021/08/13/6348/ .

This seems to provide the 'geos_c.h' file mentioned.

After this, `pip install cartopy` worked properly for me.